# Can't remove last List<T> index on ListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, methods, listbox

I can't remove my last List selected item on my ListBox by a weird reason. Everything else works perfectly and I can remove my List  selected indexes on the ListBox, but not the very last one on the listBox.

Here is my methods for deleting:

My DeleteButton:

```
'This is the Deletebutton event handler. It first checks that an index has 
'been selected before deleting
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click


    If (CheckSelectedIndex()) Then


        Dim list = listResults.SelectedIndex

        m_contacts.DeleteContact(list)
        UpdateGUI()
    End If
End Sub
```

My delete method in the ContactManager class.

```
'This is the DeleteContact. It has index as parameter and simply removes a 
    'contactRegistry at the given index.
    Public Sub DeleteContact(index As Integer)

        m_contactRegistry.RemoveAt(index)

    End Sub
```

It probably has something to do with the index but I cant find the problem..

Comment: It looks like you are deleting from the List, not the listbox.  That would work if the list was bound to the control.

Comment: But it is supposed to remove from the List<T>, and after it has been removed, the ListBox should not display it.

Comment: Did you try running in debug mode. What value does `index` have while in `DeleteContact`?

Comment: It has the value of the SelectedIndex of the listbox